# How to call merge module custom action from Installshield DoAction event?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action, merge-module

I have a custom action in merge module and I am redistributing the merge module through InstallShield. Using DoAction event, I have called the merge module custom action on button click from InstallShield. But the custom action was not performed on button click. So I want to know how to call a merge module custom action from install shield on DoAction control event.

Comment: Do you mean you have created an MSI that consumes the merge module, or an installer that installs the .msm file to the target machine's hard drive? The former should work fine or issue an explicit error, so you may need to add more information to your question (such as you can tell the action was not performed).

Comment: If using your MSM normally this should not be a problem. Please provide the log output.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already made sure custom action is being added to the correct dialog but you are not selecting the mm from a dropdown [in IS2016], check if adding the module id after the module name helps.  "modulename.moduleid"